# Can't import xlsx file in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

When trying to import an Excel file in RStudio, I receive a popup noting:

```
Is this a valid Excel file?

.onLoad failed din loadNamespace() for "cli", details:
call: asNamespace("cli")$get_ppid()
error: object "clic_getppid'not found
```

In the console, I get the following message:

```
Error in glue(str, .envir = .envir, .transformer = transformer, .cli = TRUE,  : 
  object 'glue_' not found"
```

I've tried:

(a) Reinstalling the cli and glue packages.

(b) Reinstalling R and RStudio.

(c) Googleling the error prompts (with quotes).

(d) Triple-checked that my file is in .xlsx format.

Comment: Are you using code or just the import panel in R?

Comment: The part of the error that references `glue` most likely just means that the error came up while sticking file names together to create the error message. What code are you using to import the file?

Comment: I'm using the import panel (Environment -> Import Dataset). The code it generates is:

`library(readxl)
filename <- read_excel("filename.xlsx")
View(filename)`

(The file is in the working directory.)

Comment: Have you tried importing the file in code, _not_ with the import panel? Or with different packages that read excel files?

Comment: Yes, using the xlsx package works. Thanks for the workaround, although I'm still interested in how to get rid of the original error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I lied when I said I had reinstalled both R and RStudio. These applications have a lot of hidden folders [for more information](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State). Once I deleted them and reinstalled everything, it's now working again.